# Sorting a structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure, bubble-sort

I wanted to sort this problem in C with something like bubble sort ... anyone can help

- Implement a list with 5 struct Point (Being this a point w/ X, y);
- Sort the 5 struct point (first evaluate x then y).

Example:

```
  // The points 
  p[0]={2,3}
  p[1]={4,5}
  p[2]={1,5}
  p[3]={4,3}
  p[4]={1,2}

  // Should become

  p[0]={1,2}
  p[1]={1,5}
  p[2]={2,3}
  p[3]={4,3}
  p[4]={4,5}
```

Comment: What code did you write so far?

Comment: Are you familiar with callbacks? Do you understand the answer @zixuan gave?

Comment: I'm not a pro in C but I want to be like this soon that's why I'm practicing on such problems .... my code so far is (in the next comment)

Comment: struct point
{
   int x, y;

};
int main()
{
int n;
scanf("%d",n);

   struct point  p[n];

   for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

    scanf("%d",p[i].x);
    scanf("%d",p[i].y);

   }
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
for(int i = 0 ; i < n -i-1 ; i++){
  if (p[i].x > p[i+1].x){

            int temp = *p[i].x;
            *p[i].x = *p[i+1].x;
            *p[i+1].x = temp;

            int temp = *p[i].y;
            *p[i].y = *p[i+1].y;
            *p[i+1].y = temp;
}}}
for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
    printf("%d", p[j].x);
    printf("%d", p[j].y);
}
   return 0;
}

Comment: Wait... was your question tagged as `c++`  before? Did you remove the tag?

Comment: I ask because the answer you received is for c++ only...

Comment: no, it was C from the beginning ...

Comment: I will build a proper answer, but it will take some time... now i have something else to finish.

Comment: take your time )

Comment: @CSstudent see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP is asking for a C solution, so here you go:

```
void bsortDesc(struct yourStruct list[80], int s)
{
    int i, j;
    struct yourStruct temp;

    for (i = 0; i < s - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (s - 1-i); j++)
        {
            if (list[j].marks < list[j + 1].marks)
            {
                temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
                list[j + 1] = temp;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here's what I got it from: [here](http://www.cprogrammingnotes.com/question/sorting-structure-array.html).

Comment: You should also add a definition for the `custom_sort` function so he can understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Okay. I will add the def.

Comment: can I do it in such an easier way than this :)

Comment: I think that this is the only way to go. It's hard but not impossible. @CSstudent

Comment: @zixuan was this question tagged as `c++` when you answered? Because the OP is now asking for the `c` solution...

Comment: is this way is only for C++ ?

Comment: Check the web. I dunno.

Comment: yeah but not in this case

Comment: @zixuan surely )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort structures, you still have to break it down into comparing numeric types. With this in mind, let's take your example with the points:

```
struct tagPoint
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
typedef struct tagPoint Point;
```

Now, let's suppose you have an array of `Point` and you want it sorted. You can take two approaches:

**1. Straightforward function which sorts the array:**

Just make the function to sort the array:

```
void SortPointArray(Point* Points, unsigned int n)
{
    /* This will sort the points with priority on the x and then the y value in ascending order. */
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (Points[i].x > Points[j].x)
            {
                Point aux = Points[i];
                Points[i] = Points[j];
                Points[j] = aux;
            }
            else if ((Points[i].x == Points[j].x) && (Points[i].y > Points[j].y))
            {
                Point aux = Points[i];
                Points[i] = Points[j];
                Points[j] = aux;
            }
        }
}
```

**2. Wrap the algorithm in a generic function and use callbacks for each type you want to sort:**

This is a little more complicated, but it will save you some time if you use it frequently. Here, this function uses the same algorithm as the one above, but can sort any types.

```
void Sort(void* lpArray, unsigned int n, size_t cbSize, int (*Cmp)(void*, void*), void (*Swap)(void*, void*))
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
            /* Cast void* to char* to get rid of warning with pointer arithmetic... */
            if ( Cmp( ((char*)lpArray) + i*cbSize, ((char*)lpArray) + j*cbSize) )
                Swap( ((char*)lpArray) + i*cbSize, ((char*)lpArray) + j*cbSize );
}
```

As you can see, it requires 2 more functions passed as parameters. If you want this `Sort` function to know how to sort the `Point` array, you must define a `Comparrison` function and a `Swapping` function and tell the `Sort` function to use them.

Here is how i implemented them:

```
/** This function return 1 if p1 should be swapped with p2. */
int ComparePoints(void* vp1, void* vp2)
{
    Point *p1, *p2;
    p1 = vp1;
    p2 = vp2;

    if (p1->x > p2->x)
        return 1;
    else if ((p1->x == p2->x) && (p1->y > p2->y))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}



/** This will swap 2 points. */
void SwapPoints(void* vp1, void* vp2)
{
    Point p = *(Point*)vp1;
    *(Point*)vp1 = *(Point*)vp2;
    *(Point*)vp2 = p;
}
```

---

**How do you use them?**

If you only want to use the first `SortPointArray` function, this is enough:

```
int main()
{
    Point Array[10];

    /* Read the points. */
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        scanf("%d %d", &Array[i].x, &Array[i].y);

    SortPointArray(Array, 10);

    /*Print the points.*/
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", Array[i].x, Array[i].y);

    return 0;
}
```

But if you want to use the generic `Sort` function (which i recommend only if you have multiple types you want to sort like `Point`s, `Line`s etc) you have to define the two callbacks (`ComparePoints` and `SwapPoints`)

```
int main()
{
    Point Array[10];

    /* Read the points. */
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        scanf("%d %d", &Array[i].x, &Array[i].y);

    Sort(Array, 10, sizeof(Point), ComparePoints, SwapPoints);

    /*Print the points.*/
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", Array[i].x, Array[i].y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I got the idea now ... so basically I missed some declarations before the function ... this is a great answer and explanation... thank u for your effort and the world will improve fast as long we help each other. :)